# How can infinite scrollview anchor be maintained?

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, android-scrollview

I have a custom scrollview, source code here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e605afc18a5a1edd5429c19a1092da2c#file-customscrollview-java.
Whenever new items are loaded on top and bottom on *initial* load, the anchor jumps when the control falls through this `if` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e605afc18a5a1edd5429c19a1092da2c#file-customscrollview-java-L466.

This question is particularly related to how to maintain anchor position when the `scrollY` exceeds max `scrollY` for scrollview?

Comment: what do you mean by `"infinite scrollview"`? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink i want to achieve a scrollview which maintains its anchor, when new items are added at the start or end of it.

Comment: This implementation actually modifies the scrollview used by react native internally.

Comment: so if you want such "infinite scrollview" then you should most likely use `RecyclerView` instead of custom `ScrollView`

Comment: Yeah, but turns out its harder to implement a recyclerview as a native module in react native rather than using the already implemented scrollview with clipped views optimisation (to remove views not on screen - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the problem was somewhere else, the code is fine ;)